# Retain a value after page refresh ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used this code to retain a value after page refresh. It has been used to retain a where clause so every time after I update my data, the gridview still shows the search result based on this retained clause. It has been working fine till today when I realize it does not work anymore, it refreshes along with the page. It is a weird situation so I would like to ask if there is anything wrong with this code.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scripttb" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="paneltb" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_whereClause" runat="server" Visible="True"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

C# code

```
 public class SearchInput
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string department { get; set; }
    }

    private SearchInput GetSearchInput()
    {
        return new SearchInput()
        {
            id = txt_id.Text,
            email = txt_email.Text,
            stdepartment = ddl_department.SelectedItem.Text,
        };
    }
private string stWhereClause()
    {
        SearchInput searchInput = GetSearchInput();
        string stwhereClause = " WHERE 1=1 ";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchInput.idmnv))
            stwhereClause += string.Format("AND ID LIKE '%{0}%' ", searchInput.id);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchInput.email))
            stwhereClause += string.Format("AND Email LIKE '%{0}%' ", searchInput.email);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchInput.department))
            stwhereClause += string.Format("AND CONTAINS ([Department], '" + '"' + searchInput.department + '"' + "')");
        return stwhereClause;
    }
```

Every time I search, I will store my SQL search function into lbl_whereClause

```
lbl_stwhereClause.Text = stWhereClause();
```

Then I expect that after I update, this lbl_stwhereClause is kept the same

Comment: We see markup, but no code.

Comment: issue seems that you have a update panel wrapped around the label. That should not be required. I also don't see where you are setting the label value in above. But, a simple set of that label text value should work - but in posted code, I don't see any place in which you are setting the label text value.  So yes, the label should retain and save your filter into the label, but I don't see any code where this occurs. Regardless, I see no reason for introduction of a update panel, and it only going to cause issues for you unless there is a boatload of additional things in the update panel.